# RTabMap Cannot locate node

Tags: ros

So I Just installed RTabMap and whenever I try to run a launch file or demo I get these errors

> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rtabmap_ros/rgbd_odometry]: can't locate node [rgbd_odometry] in package [rtabmap_ros]
>   ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rtabmap_ros/rtabmap]: can't locate node [rtabmap] in package [rtabmap_ros]
>   ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rtabmap_ros/rtabmapviz]: can't locate node [rtabmapviz] in package [rtabmap_ros]

The full message is this

> roslaunch rtabmap_ros rtabmap.launch rtabmap_args:="--delete_db_on_start" depth_topic:=/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw rgb_topic:=/camera/color/image_raw camera_info_topic:=/camera/color/camera_info approx_sync:=false
>   ... logging to /home/crosswing/.ros/log/dd12b432-4a6c-11e9-8dce-f8633f5d5fe3/roslaunch-crosswing-NUC7i5BNH-7688.log
>   Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
>   Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
>   Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
>
> PARAMETERS
>    * /rosdistro: melodic
>    * /rosversion: 1.14.3
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/approx_sync: False
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/config_path: 
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/frame_id: camera_link
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/ground_truth_base_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/ground_truth_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/guess_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/guess_min_rotation: 0.0
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/guess_min_translation: 0.0
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/odom_frame_id: odom
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/publish_tf: True
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/queue_size: 10
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/subscribe_rgbd: False
>    * /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry/wait_for_transform_duration: 0.2
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/Mem/IncrementalMemory: true
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/Mem/InitWMWithAllNodes: false
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/approx_sync: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/config_path: 
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/database_path: ~/.ros/rtabmap.db
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/frame_id: camera_link
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/ground_truth_base_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/ground_truth_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/landmark_angular_variance: 9999.0
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/landmark_linear_variance: 0.0001
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/map_frame_id: map
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_sensor_sync: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_tf_angular_variance: 1.0
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/odom_tf_linear_variance: 1.0
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/publish_tf: True
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/queue_size: 10
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/scan_normal_k: 0
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_depth: True
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_odom_info: True
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_rgbd: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_scan: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_scan_cloud: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_stereo: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/subscribe_user_data: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmap/wait_for_transform_duration: 0.2
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/approx_sync: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/frame_id: camera_link
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/odom_frame_id: 
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/queue_size: 10
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/subscribe_depth: True
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/subscribe_odom_info: True
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/subscribe_rgbd: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/subscribe_scan: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/subscribe_scan_cloud: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/subscribe_stereo: False
>    * /rtabmap/rtabmapviz/wait_for_transform_duration: 0.2
>
> NODES
>     /rtabmap/
>       rgbd_odometry (rtabmap_ros/rgbd_odometry)
>       rtabmap (rtabmap_ros/rtabmap)
>       rtabmapviz (rtabmap_ros/rtabmapviz)
>
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rtabmap_ros/rgbd_odometry]: can't locate node [rgbd_odometry] in package [rtabmap_ros]
>   ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rtabmap_ros/rtabmap]: can't locate node [rtabmap] in package [rtabmap_ros]
>   ERROR: cannot launch node of type [rtabmap_ros/rtabmapviz]: can't locate node [rtabmapviz] in package [rtabmap_ros]

Can anybody help me figure out what the issue is and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: Same issue for me. I found a similar post in [Github](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/issues/7), but did not help me either.

Answer (score 0):

This Error means that ROS system cannot find your `rgbd_odometry` Node inside `rtabmap_ros` package or cannot find `rtabmap_ros` package altogether.

First, check if your package is inside your ROS PATH (`ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment) then check if `rospack` can find the package or not. if you compiled it from source check for Compilation Error. if all checked out with no problem, use `rosrun` command to check if you can run the package with no configuration.

**EDIT1**

after Checking CMakeList.txt in [RtabMap_ros Github](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros) it appears they changed the name of the node from `rgbd_odometry` to `rtabmap_rgbd_odometry` [Check CMakeLists Here](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L339)

you can check installed Nodes of every package in lib folder of your workspace(for instance you can check nodes installed in your catkin worksapce by finding them at `<your_catking_workspace>/devel/lib/<package_name>` )

Comment: Rospack did find the rtabmap_ros package. I checked my rtabmap_ros package and there is no file named rgbd_odometry. I'm not sure why its missing as I cloned the package. Is there something I'm missing I don't know about. Please let me know if what I'm saying makes sense. I'm very inexperienced and I don't fully understand most things.

Comment: No, they didn't change the name, they simply followed the new ROS convention to call the CMake target name something other than the executable, see 2 lines down from the one you posted.

Comment: That is True. But Still you can find their name in said folder or in workspace or in case of installing in main ros package path.